# Cakephp 3 Allow Duplicate in BelongsToMany

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a `Table` which has a `belongsToMany` property to another `Table`.
Let's say `Products` `belongsToMany` `Contracts`, through a join table `ContractProducts`.
When I submit form data, I need also duplicate values. So, I submit data like this:

```
$data['products']['_ids'] = [0 => 109, 1 => 109]
```

But when I apply the `patchEntity` method, the patched `Entity` does not contain duplicated values but just one.

Is it possible to submit duplicate data in `patchEntity` ?

Comment: I checked the code and apparentlely it is not possible

Comment: It makes no sense to link a product to a contract twice, unless you have additional `_joinData`. Then it is no longer possible via `_ids`).